# Типы связей в БД и их графическое изображение

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Какая разница в связях изображенных сплошной и пунктирной линией (в ЕРД диаграмме и т.д., и т.п.)? Подразумевается соотношение один ко многим.

Значение не имеет, но... диаграмма из ERwin, dbForge Studio MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По ERwin вырезка:

- Сплошная - Идентифицирующая связь: При установлении идентифицирующей связи дочерняя сущность автоматически превращается в зависимую. Атрибуты первичного ключа родительской сущности автоматически мигрируют в зону атрибутов первичного ключа дочерней сущности как внешние ключи (Foreign Key)
- Пунктир - Не идентифицирующая связь: При установлении неидентифицирующей связи дочерняя сущность не превращается в зависимую, а ключевые атрибуты родительской сущности мигрируют в область неключевых атрибутов дочерней сущности

Более чем понятно на мой взгляд